# utf8 characters in custom url scheme

Tags: url, url-scheme

I made a custom url scheme.

when the keyword is in English it's OK.

NSLog :

myscheme://withkeyword/?keyword=english

When the keyword is in Korean, in Japanese etc, look like the below.

NSLog :

myscheme://withkeyword/0.000000keyword=2.122748E-314D99C3.246487E-314AB88

What's wrong?

Comment: You'll have to provide a lote more details, for instance - how exactly are you generating the URL? Which programming language are you using? etc.

Answer (score 0):

The allowed characters for custom URI schemes are defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Basically, they consist of `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and these characters: `-` `,` `.` `_` `~`. Korean and Japanese are considered 'unsafe' for URIs, which is why you're seeing the bizarre results above.

You need to percent encode those non-Latin characters before inserting them into the URI string. There are a ton of resources discussing how best to do this depending on your specific situation, but the best place to start is probably [`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:)